# ExtJS, FormPanel show() function issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I want to use FormPanel show() function to show it as pop up.
But below code does not show anything. but If I pass this formPanel to a ExtJS Window object and calling window show() function works fine. 
I want to avoid creating a new Window object just to show a form panel. How do I do that?

```
    var formPanelItems = ...
    var formPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
       width: 300px,
       height: 300px,
       items        : formPanelItems,
    });
    formPanel.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Per Ext's doc, you need to set config property `floating:true` and explicitly set the position of it after render because it is absolute positioned.

A sample:

```
var p = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        title:'test', 
        width: 300, 
        height: 150, 
        html:'a floating panel', 
        floating: true, 
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
}); 
p.setPosition(200,200);
```

Comment: `renderTo: Ext.getBody()` should center the panel, itself; therefore, `setPosition()` may not be necessary (I use Ext 5.*).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set config property `floatable: true`. It will tell the control to render itself not to some parent element on the page, but directly to `body`

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Panel3.html#Ext-panel-Panel-cfg-floatable

Comment: We have ExtJS version 3.1, floatable option is not available in this version. Any idea on what is the similar option in 3.1?

Comment: I've checked my local docs for 3.1 revision and its there (derived from `Ext.Panel`. Also it exists in 3.4 version online http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.FormPanel-cfg-floating

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this, might be useful:
[Dockable/floatable panels in ExtJS?](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?16842-Dockable-floatable-panels-in-ExtJS)